# Selecting latest document in ledger data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB document schema that looks like below

```
{
 "primary_key": "xxxx",
 "value": [{data: latest },...]
 "updated_at": 2022-01-01 00:00:00Z
}
```

the collection is an append-only ledger, the combination of `primary_key` and `updated_at` is unique.

How can I query all the latest data based on `updated_at` for all the `primary_key` using aggregate?

the final result should look like

```
[{
  "primary_key": "xxxx",
  "value": [{data: latest_data_for_xxxx },...]
  "updated_at": 2022-01-01 00:00:00Z
},{
  "primary_key": "yyyy",
  "value": [{data: latest_data_for_yyyy},...]
  "updated_at": 2022-01-01 00:00:00Z
}]
```

p.s: please don't suggest the solution to query data one at a time for the key

```
db.collection.find_one({"primary_key": xxxx}).sort({"updated_at": -1})
```

this doesn't seem efficient at all. repeating it for million unique data will not be a feasible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking for the answer, the docs really helped

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  $sort: { primary_key: 1, updated_at: -1},
  $group: { _id: "$primary_key", values: {$first: "$values"} }
])
```